# open dropdown with ng-class Angularjs and typescript

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, typescript, drop-down-menu

I need to open the dropdown when clicking on link with angularjs. my idea is to add the class open to the dropdown with ng-class directive but this is not working .

I have two dropdown menu, what i need is to open the second one when clicking on the link within the first one

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right " >
         <li class="dropdown" ng-class="myDropdown ? : 'open'">
             <a  class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" >Menu</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu " role="menu" ng-if="!myDropdown">
                   <li>
                      <a href="" ng-click=" toogleDropDown()">Open second dropdown</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul  class="dropdown-menu " role="menu" ng-if="myDropdown">
                   <li >
                      <a href="" ng-click="!toogleDropDown()">Go back</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
          </li>
    </ul>
```

Typescript

```
 toogleDropDown() {
        this.scope.myDropdown = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This won't work since you toggleDropDown is a function and it does not return anything !undefined should be true I think so your line:

```
<a href="" ng-click="!toogleDropDown()">Go back</a>
```

is same as writing:

```
<a href="" ng-click="true">Go back</a>
```

overall there's no need for that function at all what you need is something like this:

```
  <a href="" ng-click="myDropdown=!myDropdown">
               <span ng-if="!myDropdown">Open second dropdown</span>
               <span ng-if="myDropdown">Go back</span>
            </a>
```

and remove that function from your controller there's no need for it.

also I believe you wanted to set up ng-class like this:

```
<li class="dropdown" ng-class="{'open': myDropdown}">
```

Here's fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pegla/nq11093m/1/